# The rsa formula can give different results even though the codes are not changed

Tags: rsa

sorry for my english. (Translated by google translate)

planned text(ascii) 119, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 115 (windows)

Example p=61, q=53 runs without error. However, although I did not make any changes in the codes, if e(157), d(5493) in the example of p=111, q=113 (mod=12543, phiN=12320); result= 4187, 105, 110, 778, 111, 4187, 3505. (The modular exponentiation calculations for e and d are correct) However, I would like to draw your attention; YYY, 105, 110, YYY, 111, YYY, YYY were found in the results. It finds the planned text in the same group (with the same formula) as correct or incorrect. PS: YYY: wrong result (result found different from planned text) Where might I be missing a trick. I would be glad if you help. Good work…

Comment: **111 is not prime**. RSA does not work correctly if the 'primes' are not prime.

Comment: You reminded me that I need to study more. Thanks. I wish you success in your work.